# Error when using Merkle Proof with a lot of leaves

Tags: merkleization, proof, merkle

I have merkle proof integrated into our smart contract to implement a whitelist. It works nicely, but when I use a list of a lot of addresses (around 200), I run into issues. The proof for any address in this tree is an array of 8 hashes, and when putting that into the smart contract I keep getting 'false' as the result, even though I'm getting 'true' in my local environment. Am I not supposed to put in all 8 hashes for the proof or is there something else I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: How do the block gas limits compare between your local environment and the other environment?

Comment: My local environment is just running javascript functions, the smart contract is on Rinkeby. Planning to use on Eth mainnet

Comment: "just running javascript functions" sounds like you are running Ganache. I am asking about the environment because transactions are limited by the block gas limit. This is what you might be hitting with your monster transaction. And different environments have different block gas limits.

Comment: What does the contract do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I wasn't sorting the leaves which meant the proof was not accurate. Here's how I fixed it:
In the line of code where I create the tree I added an option that sorts the proof

```
  const tree = new MerkleTree(leaves, keccak256, {sortPairs: true})
```